# Bootstrap rails gem: customize which JS components are included?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

With the bootstrap rails gem, we are able to customize which CSS to include like this:

```
@import "bootstrap/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/root";
@import "bootstrap/reboot";
@import "bootstrap/type";
@import "bootstrap/images";
```

But on the JS side, the following includes ALL of the Bootstrap components:

```
require bootstrap-sprockets
```

Is there a way to include some of Bootstrap's JS components and not everything to remove bloat?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. it is possible. 
I have this gem installed

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
```

and the application.js

```
// Only require the bootstrap parts we need  //= require bootstrap-sprockets
// Collapse and dropdown for nav 
//= require bootstrap/modal
//= require bootstrap/collapse
//= require bootstrap/dropdown
```

Comment: Is there a list of all these components that can be included? Couldn't it find it in the gem documentation.